# Define document schema in MongoEngine for existing collection

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

This is my first time using Mongoengine and mongodb and I am stuck with an use case. I need to use an already existing collection with mongoengine and I am not sure how the mapping of the fields in the actual collection to the class attributes work. I am guessing it is order dependent but then how will we define document class for an use case like below when different documents in the same collection do not have exactly the same schema :

```
document 1
 "field_1" : "abc"
"field_3" : "pqr"
"field_4" : "qwe"
"field_5" : "ert"


document 2
"field_1" : "awc"
"field_2" : "prrqr"
"field_4" : "qwe"
```

Thanks

Comment: I figured out how to do it. I guess mongoengine is both order dependent and also looks at the field names.
I defined a single class with attributes for all (field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4,field_5) and off course I set the meta option for collections.

Comment: Correction to the comment above,  I guess mongoengine looks at the field names